# How to configure `requests.get(url)` calls with retries without creating a new session?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I want to use have fault-tolerance for `requests.get(url)` with a maximum number of 3 retries.

Currently, I create a new session and pass that around between methods, which I would like to avoid:

```
with requests.Session() as rs:
     rs.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=3))
     rs.get(url)
     ...
```

Is there any way to configure the `requests.get(url)` call, such that it retries requests to the server in case it fails?

Comment: Loop it till it's true?

Comment: What do you mean by true? Do you refer to the HTTP status?

Comment: `While True: try: requests.get() break expect: pass`

Comment: Does my answer help you?

Comment: Yes thank you, although I’d hoped for native Requests support, like through a parameter.

Comment: Yeah I get it but till now they haven't had it :)

Comment: I'll update my answer and let you know when they add so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a dirty implementation:

```
import requests
from time import sleep
While True:
    try:
        #requests here
        break
    except:
        sleep(1)
```

But setting a retry of 3:

```
import requests
from time import sleep
for i in range(3):
    try:
        #requests here
        break
    except:
        sleep(1)
```

A good practice:

```
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry


def requests_retry_session(
    retries=3,
    backoff_factor=0.3,
    status_forcelist=(500, 502, 504),
    session=None,
):
    session = session or requests.Session()
    retry = Retry(
        total=retries,
        read=retries,
        connect=retries,
        backoff_factor=backoff_factor,
        status_forcelist=status_forcelist,
    )
    adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
    session.mount('http://', adapter)
    session.mount('https://', adapter)
    return session
response = requests_retry_session().get('https://www.example.com/')
print(response.status_code)

s = requests.Session()
s.auth = ('user', 'pass')
s.headers.update({'x-test': 'true'})

response = requests_retry_session(session=s).get(
    'https://www.example.com'
)
```

- Each retry attempt will create a new Retry object with updated values, so they can be safely reused.
- Documentation is [Here](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.util.html#module-urllib3.util.retry).
  Note that:

> Patching the HTTPAdapter.init() defaults helps you (very much not
>   recommended).

Comment: `requests.adapters.DEFAULT_RETRIES = 5` won't work because by the time the statement is executed, `requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter.__init__` is already defined with a default value of `0` for `max_retries`.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all since the OP specifically wants to avoid creating a new session and passing it around.

Comment: How does instantiating a `requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries = 3)` help at all? It is discarded right after the call and is not going to be used anywhere else.

Comment: Your note applies only to `requests.adapters.DEFAULT_RETRIES = 3` but not `requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries = 3)`. All that `requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries = 3)` does is instantiating a new object and discarding it.

Comment: Also, `requests.adapters.DEFAULT_RETRIES = 3` is pointless with monkey-patching. With monkey-patching you won't be needing the value of `requests.adapters.DEFAULT_RETRIES`.

Answer (score -1):

You can override `HTTPAdapter.__init__` with one that sets a default value for the `max_retries` argument with `functools.partialmethod`, so that the desired retry behavior is applied globally:

```
from functools import partialmethod
requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter.__init__ = partialmethod(
    requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter.__init__, max_retries=3)
...
requests.get(url)
```